# "ISO Image Scan Failure" Error When Creating Windows To Go USB Stick using Rufus on Parallels Desktop on Mac

Tags: windows, windows-11, parallels, rufus, windows-to-go

I am trying to use Rufus on my Mac running Parallels desktop to create a Windows 11 To Go USB stick. I have properly connected the USB stick, which is formatted as FAT32, and have verified that the checksums for the Microsoft website downloaded Windows 11 ISO image are correct using MD5: 8f76997f66850b0beab0359ab36d167c.

However, when I attempt to use the "Windows to Go" option in Rufus, I receive an `ISO image scan failure` error. This same error also occurs when attempting to create a Windows 10 To Go USB stick using the same method. The standard Windows Installation works but Windows to Go doesn't.

I have not been able to find any information about this particular error and am seeking help to determine what could be causing the issue and how to resolve it.

Checksums
[image: 1]

Error:
[image: 2]

---

Edit: I have attempted to use this guide https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/clean-install-windows-11 to create two partitions on the USB, one Fat32 and one NTFS. Same issue persists.

Multiple partition image scan failure:
[image: 3]

Comment: Have you seen the step-by-step guide at https://pureinfotech.com/rufus-create-bootable-windows-11-22h2-usb/ ? That said, Windows to Go is *very* limited. While most versions of Linux run well from external media, Windows is less likely to work, and will have issues if the media is used to boot a different PC from that on which it was made.

Comment: You may want to post the log from Rufus in order to get proper help. You can access the log by clicking the small blue button on the left of `START` in your screenshot, or by pressing `Ctrl`-`L` in Rufus.

Comment: I just had this problem. Turned out to be a problem with the ISO file. I downloaded it on a linux computer and moved to a windows one. That caused a corruption. Directly downloading the ISO on a windows computer solved it (use a linux computer to get the link from Microsoft).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem with the ISO file. I downloaded it on a linux computer and moved to a windows one. That caused a corruption. Directly downloading the ISO on a windows computer solved it (use a linux computer to get the link from Microsoft). -@Julius

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem. The logs said Ventoy could scan the iso due to a filesystem issue.

As I'm running Rufus in a Windows VM and the iso is on the host system, shared with the VM via VMware Shared Folders, I figured that's the issue. I copied the iso into the VM's local virtual disk and Ventoy proceeded wit the scanning.

Since VMware Shared Folders is basically just like a network drive to the VM, if your ISO is on a network drive, you should try copying it onto the local hard drive.